# Insert into TableA from TableB where FieldX Value does not exist yet

Tags: mysql, insert

I am able to do a basic insert into table A from table B, however I am looking to do so only when a record exists in TableA does not yet exist in TableB as defined by FieldX.

Comment: What are we supposed to do with these words? You want to insert into tableA if the record exists in tableA? Show us some code and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to insert in TableA records that exist in TableB based on FieldX, you can try something like,

```
INSERT INTO TableA (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM   TableB
WHERE  FieldX not in (select FieldX from TableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

For better performance use the below Query:

```
insert into tableA (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3
from tableB b
left join TableA a on a.FieldX=b.FieldX
where a.FieldX is null
```